# Get query string instead of executing it in parameterized queries

Tags: php, sqlsrv

For debugging purposes I like to get the actualy query that would be send to and executed by sqlsrv. However I don't figure out how.

example:

```
$res = sqlsrv_query("SELECT * FROM some_table
    WHERE some_col = ? AND some_other_col = ?",
    array($_GET['some_val'], $_GET['some_other_val'])
);
```

What I need is essentially this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table
    WHERE some_col = " . $_GET['some_val'] .
    " AND some_other_col = " . $_GET['some_other_val'];
```

However with proper escaping, which I can then copy & paste into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Following some hints on SO, we tried to misuse `mysql_real_escape_string`, however not only is that unclean it also needs an active MySQL connection. `mysql_escape_string` is deprecated on our PHP installation already, so we don't want to use that either.

/edit:
Again, to clarify: I want an SQL command copy&paste-able with the question marks expanded by the actual but correctly (SQL-)quoted values.
Also, I do not want to do it by hand, because a) that's generally error prone and b) then either I don't have a guarantee, that I got the same query as executed by the server OR I open up my code to SQL injections again when I do an error. I do NOT need the quoted SQL command to be HTML-quoted (or if I need it I know how to use htmlentites on the string to do so).

Comment: What happens when you echo the 2nd query statement (the one with the values passed directly to the query) ?

Comment: You mean the $sql = "..." line? Then I get an SQL injection ;)

Comment: You can try `var_dump($_GET)` to see what are the values. Additionally, for testing purposes, you can consider using `htmlentities($_GET['some_val'])` to handle SQL injection. http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php. Since it is all for debugging purposes, it should not matter much anyway.

Comment: You can also use `htmlentities()` when using prepared statements but then you might have to use `html_entity_decode()` to display the values. http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: Again, to clarify: I want an SQL command copy&paste-able with the question marks expanded by the actual but correctly quoted values.